# How to make vim recover files from command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, vim

If it were `linux`, I'd do it like this:

```
echo "w DST_FILE | q" | vim -Esu NONE -r SWP_FILE
```

I'm trying to do the same under `windows` with `git`'s `bash`, but with no result. It hangs and doesn't create recovered file. This way it almost works:

```
vim -u NONE -r SWP_FILE
```

But I need to manually save the resulting file. The same happens when I run it from `cmd` with the same command:

```
echo "w DST_FILE | q" | vim -Esu NONE -r SWP_FILE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you pass the Vim commands with `-c`?!

```
$ vim -u NONE -r SWP_FILE -c 'w DST_FILE' -c q
```

Comment: Good question, as far as I remember, I pass commands to `stdin` because of [the example](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#-s-ex) in documentation.